# Making more screen resolutions available to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, parallels

I'm running Parallels 4.0 for Mac on my black MacBook.  Set up Ubuntu today to sandbox Linux a bit and see what it's about, as well as to have it available to test out my web designs in a Linux environment.

The setup itself was relatively painless, however I'm stuck on one point here.  When I installed WinXP on Parallels, it had an option for a 1024x640 resolution.  In Ubuntu, however, all I'm seeing is 800x600 and 1024x768.  The former is unbearably cramped, and the latter is so tall I have to scroll, which means constantly releasing the mouse to go up or down to see the rest of the screen.  I found a [tutorial](http://ask.metafilter.com/63558/How-do-I-get-ubuntu-to-recognize-my-monitors-proper-resolution-again) on how to add resolutions to Ubuntu, but when I opened `etc/X11/xorg.conf`, all I saw was a blank new file.  What can I put in there to enable 1024x600?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, somewhat.  Installing Parallels Tools made it work, but I had to downgrade to version 8 first.